# How do I register all Vue components at once in a laravel project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I'm a begginer so I'm sorry if I have some misunderstandings.

I have a laravel project genereted by laradock.
I wanted to use Vue.js and its components, and I editted app.js.

**`app.js`**

```js
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('my-comp', require('./components/my-comp.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

that correctly works.
Considering adding more components in the future, I replaced the code like this:

```js
const allDirents = fs.readdirSync(dirPath, { withFileTypes: true });
const fileNames = allDirents.filter(dirent => dirent.isFile()).map(({ name }) => name);
fileNames.forEach(filename => {
    Vue.component(filename.replace('.vue', ''), require(dirPath + filename).default);
})
```

But it didn't work.
`npm run dev` returns the message "Compiled successfully", but when I open a browser, browser's console outputs such messages:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:73618)
```

Can't I use Node.js's File System module In a laravel project?
I just want to know how do I get all file name in app.js in the project.
I know it will go well if I register components one by one as follows:

```js
Vue.component('my-comp1', require('./components/my-comp1.vue').default);
Vue.component('my-comp2', require('./components/my-comp2.vue').default);
...
```

But I think it's little tedious and not smart, so I'd rather not.

Does anyone have ideas or solutions?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import exampleComponent from  './components/ExampleComponent.vue'
import booking  from './components/Booking.vue'
import inquiry from './components/Inquiry'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components:{
        exampleComponent,
        booking,
        inquiry
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I'd rather not write file names more than once in app.js, if possible. After all I decided to make list object that includes component's names and process them in foreach loop like described in my post. thanks.